# Firebase Phone Number Authentication Firebase auth/argument error

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc3fv.png)

I am trying to create a authentication of phone number by getting an OTP using firebase in a JavaScript web application without REACT,NextJS or any other framework but not able to get the recaptcha and also giving again and again the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8u7y.png)
My project directories in pages from view folder in Login.ejs i want to implement the authentication but not able to do so!

firstly my project was in commonjs CJS but it was giving error so I switched to ES modules but still getting the same error!
I also tried various methods like using CDN, config file but still not able do!

```
<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth,RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js";
     (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    const firebaseConfig = {
      {config}
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);

    
    render();
    function render() {
        // window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('login-recaptcha');
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'login-recaptcha', {});
        recaptchaVerifier.render();
    }

  </script>
```

It sometimes seems like I am doing something wrong in firebase initialization.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your errors or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)